# Android Game consumes insane amount of memory on initial start of game

Tags: java, android, performance, memory-leaks, bitmap

Initially my game consumes insane amount of memory approx 500MB and then runs for some amount of time approx 5 times and then crashes.

I know it's a memory leak but can't identify so I decided to upload the whole code here and seek the help of the community.

I haven't used any frameworks and learnt from this [tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-game-development-tutorial-1/) , this is my college project. However I have modified much of the code to suit the game I wanted to make.

**MyActivity.Java**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    View.OnClickListener {
private AnimationDrawable animationDrawable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    //To portarit
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMy);
    ImageButton buttonPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    ImageButton buttonScore = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonScore);
    ImageButton buttonInstruction = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonInstruction);
    ImageButton buttonDeveloper = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonDeveloper);
    buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonScore.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonInstruction.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonDeveloper.setOnClickListener(this);

    relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mainscreen);

    animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) relativeLayout.getBackground();
    animationDrawable.start();
}

private void clearData() {
    try {
        // clearing app data
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.exec("pm clear com.lud.root.jetfighter;");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.buttonPlay:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, GameActivity.class));
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.buttonScore:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, HighScore.class));
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.buttonDeveloper:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class));
            finish();
            break;

        case R.id.buttonInstruction:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Instruction.class));
            finish();
            break;

    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are You Sure you want to exit ?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    GameView.stopMusic();
                    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                    startActivity(startMain);
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.gc();
    animationDrawable.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.releaseInstance();
    unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.rlMy));
}

private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    }
}
}
```

**GameView.JAVA**

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

volatile boolean playing;
private Thread gameThread = null;

//Adding the player to this class
private Player player;

//Objects used for drawing
private Paint paint;
private Canvas canvas;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

//Add stars list
private ArrayList<Star> stars = new ArrayList<Star>();

//Adding Enemies
private Enemy[] enemies;  // only one enemy to decrease the difficulty
private int enemyCount = 3; // Number Of Enemies

private Boom boom;

int screenX;
private boolean isGameOver;

int score;
int highScore[] = new int[6];
float distance[] = new float[enemyCount];

public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
static MediaPlayer gameOnSound;
final MediaPlayer gameOverSound;

//Context to be used in onTouchEvent on GameOver Screen , for transition from
//GameOver Screen to Main Activity
Context context;

public GameView(Context context, int screenX, int screenY) {
    super(context);
    player = new Player(context, screenX, screenY);
    this.context = context;

    //initialize drawing objects
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    paint = new Paint();

    int starNums = 50;
    for (int i = 0; i < starNums; i++){
        Star s = new Star(screenX,screenY);
        stars.add(s);
    }

    enemies = new Enemy[enemyCount];
    enemies[0] = new Enemy(context, screenX, screenY);  // This needs to be created so that the next enemies
                                                        // created can be kept apart and not overlapping
    for (int i=1; i<enemyCount; i++)
        enemies[i] = new Enemy(context, screenX, screenY, enemies[i-1].getY(),enemies[i-1].getRadius());

    boom = new Boom(context);

    boom.setX(-250);
    boom.setY(-250);

    this.screenX = screenX;
    isGameOver = false;

    score = 0;
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Scores", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //initialize the array of high scores
    highScore[0] = sharedPreferences.getInt("score1",0);
    highScore[1] = sharedPreferences.getInt("score2",0);
    highScore[2] = sharedPreferences.getInt("score3",0);
    highScore[3] = sharedPreferences.getInt("score4",0);
    highScore[4] = sharedPreferences.getInt("score5",0);

    gameOnSound = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.gameon);
    gameOverSound = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.gameover);

    gameOnSound.setLooping(true);
    gameOnSound.start();

}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (playing){
        update();
        draw();
        control();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //stopping the booster when the screen is released
            player.stopSlowing();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //starting the booster when the screen is released
            player.startSlowing();
            break;
    }
    if(isGameOver){
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context,MyActivity.class));
    }
    return true;
}

private void update() {
    //score based on the time passed
    score++;
    player.update();

    for(Star s : stars)
        s.update();

    // Below Code is for multiple enemy
    for(int i=0; i < enemyCount; i++){
        enemies[i].update((int) player.getSpeed() + 10 );
        distance[i] = (float) Math.sqrt((player.getX()-enemies[i].getX())*(player.getX()-enemies[i].getX()) + (player.getY()-enemies[i].getY())*(player.getY()-enemies[i].getY()));
        if(distance[i] < (30 + enemies[i].getRadius())){
            boom.setX(player.getX());
            boom.setY(player.getY());
            player.setX(-200);
            isGameOver = true;
            playing = false;
            gameOnSound.stop();
            gameOverSound.start();
            highScore[5] = score;
            Arrays.sort(highScore);
            Log.d("score","Score : "+score+"\nHighScores : "+highScore[0]+"\n"+highScore[1]+"\n"+highScore[2]+"\n"+highScore[3]+"\n"+highScore[4]+"\n"+highScore[5]);

            SharedPreferences pref;
            pref = context.getSharedPreferences("Scores", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor e = pref.edit();
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                e.putInt("score"+(j+1),highScore[5-j]);
                e.apply();
               Log.d("score","score"+(j+1)+"\nHighScores : "+highScore[5-j]);
            }
        }
    }

}

private void draw() {
    if(surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
        //lock the canvas
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        //setting the paint color to white to draw the stars
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        //drawing all the stars
        for (Star s : stars){
            paint.setStrokeWidth(s.getStarWidth());
            canvas.drawPoint(s.getX(), s.getY(), paint);
        }

        paint.setTextSize(30);
        canvas.drawText("Score : "+score,100,50,paint);

        //The following line is for single enemy
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        for(int i = 0; i< enemyCount; i++)
            canvas.drawCircle(enemies[i].getX(), enemies[i].getY(), enemies[i].getRadius(), paint);

        canvas.drawBitmap(boom.getBitmap(),boom.getX(),boom.getY(),paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(player.getX(), player.getY(), player.getRadius(), paint);
        if(isGameOver){
            paint.setTextSize(150);
            paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

            int yPos = (int)((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((paint.descent() + paint.ascent()))/2);
            canvas.drawText("GAME OVER",canvas.getWidth()/2, yPos,paint);
        }

        //Unlocking the canvas
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}

private void control() {
    try {
        gameThread.sleep(15);   //creating the frame rate to around 33fps
        canvas = null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void pause(){
    //pausing the game , set the variable to false
    playing = false;
    try {
        gameThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void resume(){
    playing = true;
    gameThread = new Thread(this);
    gameThread.start();
}

public static void stopMusic(){
    gameOnSound.stop();
    gameOnSound.release();
}

public static void pauseMusic(){
    gameOnSound.pause();
}

public static void resumeMusic(){
    gameOnSound.start();
}
}
```

**Player.Java**

```
public class Player {
private Bitmap bitmap;

//coordinates
private int x;
private int y;

private float speed ;
private boolean slowing, goingDown;
private int GRAVITY = -10;    // For the gravity effect on the ship

//Boundaries
private int maxY;
private int minY;
private int screenY;
private float radius;

private final float MINRADIUS = 30;
private final float MAXRADIUS = 100;

private final int POSGRAVITY = +10;
private final int NEGGRAVITY = -10;

private final int SLOWPOSGRAVITY = +4;
private final int SLOWNEGGRAVITY = -4;

public Player(Context context, int screenX, int screenY){
    x = 30; //initial x-position
    y = 50; //initial y-position
    speed = -4;
    radius = MINRADIUS;
    maxY = screenY - 30;
    this.screenY = screenY;
    minY = 30;  //equal to initial radius
    slowing = false;   //initially slowing is false
    goingDown = true;
}

public void startSlowing(){
    slowing = true;
    if(radius > MAXRADIUS)
        radius = MAXRADIUS;
    else radius += 1.5f;
    if(goingDown)
    {
        speed = -0.3f;
        GRAVITY = SLOWNEGGRAVITY;
    }
    else{
        speed = 0.3f;
        GRAVITY = SLOWPOSGRAVITY;
    }

}

public void stopSlowing(){
    slowing = false;
    if(goingDown)
    {
        speed = -4.0f;
        GRAVITY = NEGGRAVITY;
    }
    else{
        speed = 4.0f;
        GRAVITY = POSGRAVITY;
    }
}

public void update(){
    minY = (int) getRadius();
    maxY = screenY - (int) getRadius();

    if(!slowing)
        if(radius < MINRADIUS)
            radius = MINRADIUS;
        else radius -= 0.5f;
    if(slowing)
        if(radius > MAXRADIUS)
            radius = MAXRADIUS;
        else radius += 0.5f;
    // Moving the ball down
    y -= speed + GRAVITY;
    if(y < minY)
    {
        y = minY;
        if(slowing)
        {
            speed = -0.3f;
            GRAVITY = SLOWNEGGRAVITY;
        }
        else
        {
            speed = -4;
            GRAVITY = NEGGRAVITY;
        }
        goingDown = true;
        Log.d("down","Gravity : "+ GRAVITY + " Speed : "+speed+" y : "+y+" goingDown : "+goingDown);
    }
    if( y > maxY)
    {
        y = maxY;
        if(slowing)
        {
            speed = 0.3f;
            GRAVITY = SLOWPOSGRAVITY;
        }
        else
        {
            speed = 4;
            GRAVITY = POSGRAVITY;
        }
        goingDown = false;
        Log.d("down","Gravity : "+ GRAVITY + " Speed : "+speed+" y : "+y+" goingDown : "+goingDown);
    }
}

public float getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public int getX() {
    return (int) (getRadius());
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public float getRadius() {
    return radius;
}
}
```

**Enemy.Java**

```
public class Enemy {

private int x;
private int y;
private int speed = -1;
private int radius = 20;

private int maxX, minX;
private int maxY, minY;

//Create a rect object to detect collision
private Rect detectCollision;

public Enemy(Context context, int screenX, int screenY){
    maxX = screenX;
    maxY = screenY;
    minX = 0;
    minY = 0;

    // Randomly generating enemy position
    Random generator = new Random();
    speed = 25;
    radius = 35;
    x = screenX;
    y = generator.nextInt(maxY) + 10 - radius;
}

public Enemy(Context context, int screenX, int screenY, int prevY, int prevRad){
    maxX = screenX;
    maxY = screenY;
    minX = 0;
    minY = 0;

    // Randomly generating enemy position
    Random generator = new Random();
    speed = 25;
    radius = 35;
    x = screenX;
    do{
        y = generator.nextInt(maxY) + 10 - radius;
    }while ((y - prevY) < (prevRad + radius + 60));
}

public void update(int playerSpeed){
    // As the enemy moves from right to left
    x -= playerSpeed;
    x -= speed;
    Random generator = new Random();
    if(x < minX - this.getRadius()){
        speed = generator.nextInt(10) + 10;
        radius = generator.nextInt(20) + 30;
        x = maxX;
        y = generator.nextInt(maxY) - radius;
    }
}

//This setter is used for changing the x coordinate after collision
public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public Rect getDetectCollision() {
    return detectCollision;
}

public int getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getRadius() {
    return radius;
}
}
```

**Star.Java**

```
public class Star {
private int x;
private int y;
private int speed;

private int maxX;
private int maxY;
private int minX;
private int minY;

public Star(int screenX, int screenY){
    maxX = screenX;
    maxY = screenY;
    minX = 0;
    minY = 0;

    Random generator = new Random();
    speed = generator.nextInt(10);

    //generate random coordinate but keeping them inside the screen
    x = generator.nextInt(maxX);
    y = generator.nextInt(maxY);
}

public void update(){
    //To animate the stars on the left side
    //Used here is the player's speed
    x -= 10;
    x -=speed;
    if(x < 0){
        //Again start the stars from the right edge
        //Thus creating an infinite background effect
        x = maxX;
        Random generator = new Random();
        y = generator.nextInt(maxY);
        speed = generator.nextInt(15);
    }
}

public float getStarWidth(){
    //Randomising the star width , for aesthetics
    float minX = 1.0f;
    float maxX = 4.0f;
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextFloat() * (maxX - minX) + minX;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}
}
```

All these classes use **only canvas method** to draw so I suppose there shouldn't be any memory leak here, however the following Boom class which creates a boom.png when you lose the game does use a bitmap which is not being cached, this might be the problem but only a small bitmap shouldn't consume such an insane amount of memory , I did change the frame rate by the control() function in GameView class but still nothing good comes out.

**Boom.Java**

```
public class Boom {

private Bitmap bitmap;
private int x,y;

public Boom(Context context){
    //get the image from drawable
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.boom);

    //set the coordinate outside the screen so that it won't be
    //shown on the screen
    //it will be visible for only a fraction of a second
    x = -250;
    y = -250;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}
}
```

I did read about how to check for memory leak by tracing and profiling but it was too overwhelming for a newbie like me.

All those (DDMS , Android Monitor, Tracing, Profiling), however I did do that and found that (based on the data in app profiling in Android Monitor), that is what I assume was right because earlier the game was running only for 3 - 4 times, the tool showed too much taken by random function .

Earlier there were 3 calls to random in **Enemy.java** and 1 in **Star.java**

I want to know the root cause and remove that which is hindering my game.

This is from my logcat : ( I don't see any dalvikvm message related to cleanup )

```
11-24 16:17:00.844  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:00.844  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:00.864  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:00.864  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:00.883  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:00.884  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:00.903  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:00.903  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:00.925  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:00.925  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:00.946  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:00.947  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:00.968  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:00.969  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:00.990  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:00.991  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:01.025  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:01.027  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:01.047  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:01.048  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:01.052   309   451 I BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceView](this:0x7f8936e000,id:7877,api:2,p:2347,c:309) queueBuffer: fps=46.72 dur=1005.97 max=36.57 min=19.09
11-24 16:17:01.067  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:01.067  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:01.087  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:01.088  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:01.107  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:01.107  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:01.126  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:01.127  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:01.147  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:01.147  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:01.170  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:01.171  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:01.192  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:01.193  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:01.215  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:01.215  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:01.249  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Locking canvas... stopped=false, win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@ab77912
11-24 16:17:01.250  2347  2466 I SurfaceView: Returned canvas: android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@cee38e3
11-24 16:17:01.273  2347  2347 D MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(8, 0, 0)
11-24 16:17:01.276  2347  2466 D score   : Score : 329
11-24 16:17:01.276  2347  2466 D score   : HighScores : 248
11-24 16:17:01.276  2347  2466 D score   : 269
11-24 16:17:01.276  2347  2466 D score   : 317
11-24 16:17:01.276  2347  2466 D score   : 329
11-24 16:17:01.276  2347  2466 D score   : 460
11-24 16:17:01.276  2347  2466 D score   : 579
11-24 16:17:01.282  2347  2466 D score   : score1
```

This class hosts the GameView class.
**GameActivity.clas**

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    private GameView gameView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Get the display object
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    //Get the screen Resolution
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    //initialize the gameview object
    gameView = new GameView(this, size.x,size.y);
    setContentView(gameView);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    gameView.pause();
    gameView.pauseMusic();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.gc();
    gameView.resume();
    gameView.resumeMusic();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

This is the output of the `adb -d shell dumpsys meminfo com.lud.root.jetfighter` command

**Output of memory at time of hang of the game**

```
App Summary
                       Pss(KB)
                        ------
           Java Heap:     3348
         Native Heap:        0
                Code
```

:     3320
                   Stack:      332
                Graphics:    25175
           Private Other:    11696
                  System:     4691

```
               TOTAL:    48562      TOTAL SWAP (KB):    30220

 Objects
               Views:       35         ViewRootImpl:        3
         AppContexts:        5           Activities:        4
              Assets:        4        AssetManagers:        2
       Local Binders:       11        Proxy Binders:       18
       Parcel memory:        3         Parcel count:       14
    Death Recipients:        0      OpenSSL Sockets:        0
```

HPROC Analysis of My Image. I Don't know what to conclude but I suppose it is the imagebutton causing the problem:

[image]

Comment: You should use `private final Random generator = new Random();` instead of creating it all the time. It shouldn't be that bad, but when a tool complains and the remedy is trivial, then definitely go for it.

Comment: I did try that @maaartinus but still the game crashes , however it didn't crash on the initial run ..

Thanks

Comment: in GameView.java onDraw method, log how many of each item is created, i think you're making lots of bitmap and it will consume lots of memory

Comment: Actually in 15sec it drew 556 bitmaps which are not needed at the moment,
should I put it inside the isGameOver Condition cause it is only needed at that moment , the boom.png ?

Comment: @masoudvali Still it hangs after the 5th gameplay
Any further suggestions ??

Comment: @maaartinus I don't see any garbage collection threads in my log messages ....
Can it be the reason ??
I have seen logcat messsages from android studio as well as from terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android game memory management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772120/android-game-memory-management)

Comment: @Selvin It isn't a duplicate rather it is the complete picture of the problem

Comment: *...it is the complete picture of the problem*  ... So it is duplicate ... you could edit the old question instead create the new one ...

Comment: can you post the Activity which hosts your GameView?

Comment: @aelimill I have posted the activity requested

Comment: Thanks. Does the memory hugely increases during gameplay session?Or just spikes when you start the new one? You can see it in android studio -> android monitor tab -> monitors -> memory

Comment: Thanks  for continually taking efforts to solve my problem @aelimill
In monitor tab it shows consistent memory (around 189 MB) however on my phone I can see it spiking gradually and then stopping as no further memory is being allocated to the app....
When there is a spike the monitor tab shows application as **DEAD**

Comment: I think it is due to the image button I am using as seen from this image[MemoryLeak.png](https://s21.postimg.org/442h7tiiv/Memory_Leak.png)

Comment: I recommend you to make "finish()" when you make transaction to another activity and manually recycle bitmaps in onDestroy (especially for Boom)

Comment: @aelimill Where should I add finish() after the startActivity(new Intent...) or somewhere else ?? Sorry If this sounds a dumb question but I am a beginner in android

Comment: @aelimill I have even tried that now but still it's hanging after 3-4 plays

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd benefit from reading [this](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) on loading bitmaps. From my personal experience I've found that loading even small bitmaps can be hefty drain on memory when not done properly.

One thing I did notice is your draw method always draws boom.png regaurdless of if the player is hit. Rather than setting the x & y values of it to negative then making it positive after being hit, just keep track of if the player is hit. You are already doing this with isGameOver. Simply move the boom draw there, unless there is another instance where you need it drawn (from what I can tell there isn't).

Aside from that, since you say it crashes on x number of play throughs I wonder if it has something to do with how you're switching activities. Assuming you can play your game multiple times and it goes back to a main menu, I would wonder if you're keeping a back log of your old GameViews. Are you creating a new instance of GameView every time you click to play? (Feel free to post your activities)

Comment: I don't see any garbage collection threads in my log messages ....
Can it be the reason ??
I have seen logcat messsages from android studio as well as from terminal

Comment: I think so I am making new instance ....
I mean yes and how to avoid that I have posted the MyActivity.class file
and have made the changes of Boom.png as suggested

Comment: It looks like you've made some progress. You might try setting the 'android:noHistory' to true in your GameActivity. Then you wouldn't necessarily need all those finish calls. I keep wondering if you're keeping a back log of that MainActivity. You never finish it, which is fine except every time you finish the game you make a new instance of the MainActivity. Each MainActivity holds its own copy of resources which includes that background drawable. 

I'm not sure on this, as I haven't played around with this situation enough but since GameActivity is pretty set the leak might be else where.

Comment: Actually you are right since the Memory analysis did point to drawables in the main activity but how do I finish the main activity and stop it from creating it's own copy ?

Comment: Since you always create a new instance of your MainActivity when you go to it, just finish() it every time you leave or set it to have NoHistory so you don't have to worry about adding finishes everywhere.

Comment: Thanks Will look into it

Comment: it still hangs ... after implementing the NoHistory

Comment: Well, I'm out of ideas. Best of luck. :)

Comment: Anyway Thanks for bearing with me